# MUI DataGrid SingleSelect Value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I am trying to avoid building my own select and just want to set the type to singleSelect. So I have gotten to a point to where the select renders and there are options when I double click on the cell. The 2 issues I have is I am not sure how to set which option is selected and when I click on an option I get an error about `A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled`. All the docs I have seen show when your options are simple strings.

Column Definition

```
const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  …
  {
    field: ‘payment’,
    flex: 1,
    editable: true,
    type: ‘singleSelect’,
    getOptionLabel: (value: any) => value.name,
    getOptionValue: (value: any) => value.id,
    valueOptions: (params: GridValueOptionsParams<TMyProps>) => {
      const options = params.row?.attendee?.pricingOptions || [];

      if (options.length === 0) {
        return [
          id: 0,
          name: ‘No pricing options’,
        ];
      }

      return options;
    }, 
  },
  …
];
```

Rows data

```
const rows = [
  {
     id: 1,
     attendee: {
       id: 1234,
       pricingOptions: [
         {
           id: 2342342342,
           name: ‘Credit Card’,
           selectedOption: true,
         },
         {
           id: 99994,
           name: ‘Cash’,
           selectedOption: false,
         },
       ],
     }
  },
];
```

So I am not sure how to tell the data table on how to find the selected option. Also when I click on something, how do I control it?

Comment: Does all your rows have the `payment` field set to a valid value (even if it is a default or null value) from the beginning?

Comment: Ah so maybe the issue is I am not mapping field properly. The way the api works is there a property in the `pricingOptions1st called `selectedOption` and if that is true then that option is the selected one

Comment: @VonC I wonder should field: ‘payment’, be something like field: ‘attendee.pricingOptions’,?

Comment: Given this structure, if you were to set `field: ‘attendee.pricingOptions'`, it would expect the value of `attendee.pricingOptions` to be the selected value. However, `attendee.pricingOptions` is an array. You could flatten your rows' data structure for the DataGrid, adding a `payment` field to every row, which will be the `id` of the selected pricing option. Then set the field to `payment`.  When a user makes a change, you will need to handle this edit and update your original data structure (`onEditCellChangeCommit`)

Answer (score 1):

## Doubts

The MUI DataGrid only takes `ReactNode` as a valid option, so, string being a valid option is accepted for any option and to render it. You're trying to use object, but that doesn't mean you can't achieve what you're trying to achieve.

For your first issue -

> I am not sure how to set which option is selected

An option is considered based on the `field` value of the columns definition, and it'll take that value as is, if it's a valid `ReactNode` you're good to go.

As for your second issue -

> when I click on an option I get an error about A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled.

All of the MUI components make a reference check to see that in controlled state, input value is same. In your case, in one case you're returning an array manually and in other, you're returning `options` from the row. That's why MUI says that it seems you're going from uncontrolled state to controlled state.

## How to achieve this?

You'll need to make use of all the different functionalities provided through the [`GridSingleSelectColDef`](https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/grid-single-select-col-def/) interface like so -

```ts
import * as React from "react";
import {
  GridRowsProp,
  DataGrid,
  GridColDef,
  GridRowModel
} from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import { randomId } from "@mui/x-data-grid-generator";

const initialRows: GridRowsProp = [
  {
    id: randomId(),
    attendee: {
      id: randomId(),
      pricingOptions: [
        { id: randomId(), name: "Credit Card", selected: false },
        { id: randomId(), name: "Cash", selected: false },
        { id: randomId(), name: "Net Banking", selected: true },
        { id: randomId(), name: "Free", selected: false }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    id: randomId(),
    attendee: {
      id: randomId(),
      pricingOptions: [
        { id: randomId(), name: "Credit Card", selected: true },
        { id: randomId(), name: "Net Banking", selected: false },
        { id: randomId(), name: "Debit Card", selected: false },
        { id: randomId(), name: "Free", selected: false }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    id: randomId(),
    attendee: {
      id: randomId(),
      pricingOptions: [
        { id: randomId(), name: "Credit Card", selected: false },
        { id: randomId(), name: "Cash", selected: true },
        { id: randomId(), name: "Net Banking", selected: false },
        { id: randomId(), name: "Debit Card", selected: false }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    id: randomId(),
    attendee: {
      id: randomId(),
      pricingOptions: [
        { id: randomId(), name: "Credit Card", selected: false },
        { id: randomId(), name: "Cash", selected: false },
        { id: randomId(), name: "Net Banking", selected: false },
        { id: randomId(), name: "Debit Card", selected: true },
        { id: randomId(), name: "Free", selected: false }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    id: randomId(),
    attendee: {
      id: randomId(),
      pricingOptions: []
    }
  }
];

export default function SingleSelectAsObject() {
  const [rows, setRows] = React.useState(initialRows);

  const processRowUpdate = (newRow: GridRowModel) => {
    const updatedRow = { ...newRow, isNew: false };
    setRows(rows.map((row) => (row.id === newRow.id ? updatedRow : row)));
    return updatedRow;
  };

  const columns: GridColDef[] = [
    { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 320, editable: true },
    {
      field: "attendee",
      headerName: "Payment Options",
      width: 220,
      editable: true,
      type: "singleSelect",
      getOptionLabel: (value: any) => {
        return value?.name;
      },
      getOptionValue: (value: any) => value?.name,
      valueGetter: (option) => {
        const value =
          option?.value?.pricingOptions?.find((opt) => !!opt.selected)?.name ||
          "";
        return value;
      },
      valueOptions: (params) => {
        const options: Array<any> =
          rows.find((row) => row?.id === params.row?.id)?.attendee
            ?.pricingOptions || [];
        if (!options?.length) {
          options.push({
            id: randomId(),
            name: "No Pricing Option",
            selected: true
          });
          return options;
        } else {
          return options;
        }
      },
      valueSetter: (params) => {
        const newRow = {
          ...params.row,
          attendee: {
            ...params.row?.attendee,
            pricingOptions: params.row?.attendee?.pricingOptions?.map((opt) => {
              if (opt?.name === params?.value) {
                return { ...opt, selected: true };
              }
              if (opt?.name !== params?.value && !!opt?.selected) {
                return { ...opt, selected: false };
              }
              return opt;
            })
          }
        };
        return newRow;
      }
    }
  ];

  return (
    <DataGrid
      rows={rows}
      columns={columns}
      editMode="row"
      processRowUpdate={processRowUpdate}
    />
  );
}
```

Here's a [Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/datagrid-singleselect-obj-xmpsn5).

**NOTE** - I've made use of `processRowUpdate` prop, that's not necessary. I only used it because I like to. Also, keep rows in a `useState` like I've instead of using the variable directly.